# Part of opening a c# form can't understand

Tags: c#

I'm new to c# WinForms. I've got 2 questions.This code basically tells us the part of the opening of form.

First question form1_Activated or Form1_Show or button_Click I mean all of the have same stly name of form '_' and Method name.Is it syntax of just a style.

My second question is how does the program know which one should it execute first.I mean in code line is activated-bindingContextChanged-Load...
But in output it's different.So how did that happen which code make this possible

```
     private void Form1_Activated(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         Debug.Print("Activated");
     }
     private void Form1_BindingContextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         Debug.Print("BindingContextChanged");
     }
     private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         Debug.Print("Load Olayı");
     }
     private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
     {
         Debug.Print("Paint Olayı");
     }
     private void Form1_Shown(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         Debug.Print("Shown Olayı");
     }
     private void Form1_VisibleChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         Debug.Print("VisibleChanged");
     }
     private void Form1_Validated(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {
         Debug.Print("Validated");
     }       
   } 
}
```

Comment: Please read this out-loud to a friend and see if they can make sense of it, then edit your question to be more clear. As it stands, I can't figure out anything about what you are asking. We can't see your keyboard, the rest of your program, or inside your head.

Answer (score 3):

The events occur in the order Microsoft designed them to:

Via https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86faxx0d.aspx:

> The `Form` and `Control` classes expose a set of events related to application startup and shutdown. When a Windows Forms application starts, the startup events of the main form are raised in the following order:
>
> - `Control.HandleCreated`
> - `Control.BindingContextChanged`
> - `Form.Load`
> - `Control.VisibleChanged`
> - `Form.Activated`
> - `Form.Shown`
>
> When an application closes, the shutdown events of the main form are raised in the following order:
>
> - `Form.Closing`
> - `Form.FormClosing`
> - `Form.Closed`
> - `Form.FormClosed`
> - `Form.Deactivate`
>
> The `ApplicationExit` event of the `Application` class is raised after the shutdown events of the main form.

The method naming `FormName_Event` is also by design (at least in the IDE). What you see are default event handler names generated by the form designer. You can override these if you'd like.

Comment: Maybe your answer could also include the one to the other question posed, namely that the names of the methods that handle the events are arbitrary.

Answer (score 1):

The methods are event handlers. They are called by the .Net Framework runtime in response to certain events that take place for your Form object. You can set what method responds to what event in the Visual Studio designer, and you can see how they are connected by looking inside the `InitializeComponent()` for your form in it's `*.designer.cs` file. You don't have to use the `Form_Event()` convention; this is just the name created for you if you don't have an existing method waiting. You can even make the same method respond to multiple events.

Answer (score 0):

I answer the first question. Those function also be called event handlers. Their names are general style that will be auto-generated whenever you use wizard to register an event. But totally you can change it's name to whatever name you want.

The second question as @Cᴏʀʏ's ans.